# Weird character in windows powershell output file

Tags: powershell

My OS is win10, and powershell version is 7.10.pre6.

I used `ls > D:\test.txt` to list the files and wrote to a file. But I found the "Name" column had some weird characters surrounding it, as picture shows:

[image: snapshot of the output file]

I don't know why. And when I used command like grep, awk...it turned the chinese character into messy code. For example, `ls | grep -i system` would result in:

```
la---       2020/5/20   涓婂崍11:20        1386296 AppVEntSubsystemController.dll
la---       2020/6/10   涓嬪崍10:29        2190648 AppVEntSubsystems64.dll
la---       2020/8/25    涓嬪崍2:07         463168 microsoft-windows-system-events.dll
la---       2019/3/19   涓嬪崍12:44          95744 systemcpl.dll
la---       2019/3/19   涓嬪崍12:45         102912 systeminfo.exe
la---       2020/3/12    涓嬪崍1:46         510768 systemreset.exe
```

Is that a BUG of powershell? Or is there any way to set the charset? By the way, I tried `chcp 65001`, and that didn't work.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not bug.
Those characters are [ANSI color codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors), that's because you redirect raw colored output incorrectly. Operator `>` redirects text output, including color codes.

To export data try using `ls | Select FullName, CreationTime | Out-File C:\data.txt` or `ls | Export-Csv ...`

Remember, in PowerShell everything is an object, not a string.

Comment: So it is! Thanks! And the chines character problem? It seems that it treated the gbk charset as utf-8. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Use `... | Out-File -Encoding utf8` to make your data UTF-8, then you will have no problems using powershell cmdlets. Please note that `grep` is not powershell command, and default encoding can differ. `Get-Content -Path .. | Where-Object { $_ -match '\s\o\m\e regex' }` is a native powershell way

Comment: And for your purpose, you can make `Get-ChildItem | Where-Object { $_.Name.Contains('system') } | Select FullName, CreationTime | Format-Table -Autosize`

Comment: Thanks so much. That is a little complex.I need to read some docs.

Comment: You can view the colored output in Sublime Text with ANSI syntax highlight (install ANSIescape plugin to see it)